# How to display list of items in a textarea using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to display a list of items when user hits control-enter button.

I know so far that I can use jquery trigger event to open a list. But I dont know how can I display that list in the textarea so that user can select an item from the list and set it to the textarea.

```
$("textarea").trigger(some event here to open the list);
```

Comment: Post your list code and textarea so we can try on it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, try the following:

SEE the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dmymQ/48/)

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <a>Enter</a><br />
    <div>
      <textarea>

      </textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="select">
<select id="abc1">
  <option value="volvo">Option1</option>
  <option value="saab">Option2</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Option3</option>
  <option value="audi">Option4</option>
</select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#myDiv a').click(function(){
$('#select select').appendTo('#myDiv');
$('#select').css('display','block');

var text1 = $('#abc1 option:selected').val();
$('#myDiv textarea').html(text1);

    $("#abc1").change(function () {
  var str = "";
  $("#abc1 option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).text() + " ";
  });
  $("#myDiv textarea").html(str);
})
.change();

});
```

Comment: I tried the option above but the select options do not append to the textarea.

Comment: yes they do, have you seen the fiddle? Click on enter and you will see a select dropdown box. Each chosen value appends to the textarea. Isn't this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = $('textarea#msg').val();
```

or

```
var text = $("#msg").val();
```

are correct. May be you can try

```
var text = $("#msg").text();.
```

also  if you are trying to get value of textarea  on click event of button then try getting it in

```
$(document).ready().
```